# Finding the name of method in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am trying to find the method names in my html code. So I will find the method name in 'onclick' attribute and then make operations.

This is current code:

```
<div class="button" style="width: 60px; float: right;" onclick="closeModalDialog('dialogAttachmentModal');">BLABLA</div>
```

I want to write jquery like this:

```
$('closeModalDialog').attr('id','btnCloseModal');
```

And I want to show like this:

```
<div class="button" id="btnCloseModal" style="width: 60px; float: right;" onclick="closeModalDialog('dialogAttachmentModal');">BLABLA</div>
```

I know, selector must be id or class. But I want add attribute like this.(because I have more 'button' class and I want to add only one) It is possible? How can i succeed? Thx in advance and so sorry my language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the 'attribute begins with selector' for this:

```
$('[onclick^="closeModalDialog"]').prop('id', 'btnCloseModal');
```

Note that it's better practice to use `prop()` to set DOMElement properties, and also that if there are multiple elements that have that `onclick` attribute you will end up with duplicate `id` value - which will render the page invalid.

Comment: This code working on my another project but is not working this project. Probably, problem at mine :). Thanks man ;)